# How to find text wrapped in php?

Tags: php

I am new to `php`. I want to find the main text of [this page](http://pricelessproject.com/)(I mean the text displayed on the main page) so I can tweet it. I checked all the `.php` files and searched for the text inside, but I was unable to find it. Is there any way I can know where this particular paragraph would lie in the files?

Comment: Are you trying to scrape the page over the web?

Comment: check inside database , if you have phpmyadmin or similar mysql admin, open the database, click search and select all tables then search for exact phrase of 4 words from the paragraph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possibly in a mysql database. I've no way to know for sure since I don't have the source code in question. I'm suspicious of mysql, because you have checked all the files and it's not there. If you search the database, I'm almost positive you will find it there...

Comment: I opened the site using File Zilla and downloaded all the php files to check for the text. Can you help me ou from where can I see mysql details?

Comment: you have a cpanel or something like that?  check where is phpmyadmin is you have one.  then from there see my other comment under your question.

Comment: @Dreaded: Yes. I followed your advice, searched for the paragraph and found it. But, I have no experience of how to edit it. Can you please help me out?

Answer (score 1):

If you quote us some of the PHP we will have a better chance of helping you.

Do you see things like mysql, SELECT * FROM,  etc... in there?

If so, the information is most likely being read from a MYSQL database, which means you will either have to write some php to dump the data to the screen, or you will have to access the MYSQL database via something like phpmyadmin, which the server must already have installed for it to work.